# SwitchUserFilter with maintaning earlier admin user

Tags: java, spring-security

I've tried to switch user from `ADMIN` to `USER`. However after switching I notice I lose the Principal info of `ADMIN`.

How can I check if this user was switched by `ADMIN` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [spring-security 3.2 docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.html) (also applies for [version 4.0.0](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.html)):

> On a successful switch, the user's SecurityContext will be updated to reflect the specified user and will also contain an additional SwitchUserGrantedAuthority which contains the original user. Before switching, a check will be made on whether the user is already currently switched, and any current switch will be exited to prevent "nested" switches.

So, after you have switched users, when you call:

```
request.getUserPrincipal().getAuthorities()
```

for retrieving the logged user, it will contain the authorities of the current `USER` **and**  of the previous `ADMIN` user. The authorities of the previous user will be in a `SwitchUserGrantedAuthority` instance.

What I do in my code is verify if the current user has some `SwitchUserGrantedAuthority` in its authorities and add a property to that user so the client side I know that I am logged as admin, but have switched users. I used that so I could display a buttom for loging out from that user and going back to admin's page.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in following way:

```
public User getAdminLoggedAsUser() {
    try {
        return (User) (((SwitchUserGrantedAuthority) (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().toArray()[1]))
                .getSource().getPrincipal());
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when there is no Admin logged as User, bacause in this case there won't be `SwitchUserGrantedAuthority` in the array.